# Build flat array with levels from tree array in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have the following array tree in javascript:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "parentId": null,
    "description": "Item 1",
    "value": 0,
    "children": [
      {
        "id": 2,
        "parentId": 1,
        "description": "Item 1.1",
        "value": 0,
        "children": [
          {
            "id": 3,
            "parentId": 2,
            "description": "Item 1.1.1",
            "value": 0,
            "children": []
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "parentId": null,
    "description": "Item 2",
    "value": 0,
    "children": [
      {
        "id":5,
        "parentId": 4,
        "description": "Item 2.1",
        "value": 0,
        "children": []
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I want to turn it into a flat one with it's levels, like this (see level attribute):

```
[
  {
    "id":1,
    "parentId": null,
    "description":"Item 1",
    "value":0,
    "level": "1"
  },
  {
    "id":2,
    "parentId": 1,
    "description":"Item 1.1",
    "value":0,
    "level": "1.1"
  },
  {
    "id":3,
    "parentId": 2,
    "description":"Item 1.1.1",
    "value":0,
    "level": "1.1.1"
  },
  {
    "id":4,
    "parentId": null,
    "description":"Item 2",
    "value":0,
    "level": "2"
  },
  {
    "id":5,
    "parentId": 4,
    "description":"Item 2.1",
    "value":0,
    "level": "2.1"
  }
]
```

What's the best way to do this regardless of depth?

PS: I have the flat one too, but without "level" attribute and the proposal is to add this attribute based on parentId and sort list by it, like following:

Item 1
Item 1.1
Item 1.1.1
Item 2
Item 2.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to limit the solution by the depth of the array, then I suggest not to use recursion.

```js
const solution = data => {
  const stack = data.map((item, index) => ({ ...item, level: `${index + 1}` }))
  const result = []
  
  while (stack.length) {
    const item = stack.pop()
    
    const { children, ...restItem } = item
    
    stack.push(...item.children.map((child, index) => ({ ...child, level: `${item.level}.${index + 1}` })))
    
    result.push(restItem)
  }
  
  return result
}

const data = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "parentId": null,
    "description": "Item 1",
    "value": 0,
    "children": [
      {
        "id": 2,
        "parentId": 1,
        "description": "Item 1.1",
        "value": 0,
        "children": [
          {
            "id": 3,
            "parentId": 2,
            "description": "Item 1.1.1",
            "value": 0,
            "children": []
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "parentId": null,
    "description": "Item 2",
    "value": 0,
    "children": [
      {
        "id":5,
        "parentId": 4,
        "description": "Item 2.1",
        "value": 0,
        "children": []
      }
    ]
  }
]

console.log(solution(data))
```

Comment: @larz check again please, there are no nested objects and it has `level` attribute with correct value

Comment: lol please disregard my previous comment.  That's what I get for trying to multitask :)

Comment: yeah, it's happens :)

Answer (score 0):

If you recursively loop through your array (assuming that `children` will always be the key), something like this will work.

```js
const arr = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "parentId": null,
    "description": "Item 1",
    "value": 0,
    "children": [
      {
        "id": 2,
        "parentId": 1,
        "description": "Item 1.1",
        "value": 0,
        "children": [
          {
            "id": 3,
            "parentId": 2,
            "description": "Item 1.1.1",
            "value": 0,
            "children": []
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "parentId": null,
    "description": "Item 2",
    "value": 0,
    "children": [
      {
        "id":5,
        "parentId": 4,
        "description": "Item 2.1",
        "value": 0,
        "children": []
      }
    ]
  }
]

const newArray = [];

const flatten = (item, parentIdx) => {
  // separate parent from children
  item.forEach(({ children, ...child}, idx) => {
    // create level
    const level = `${parentIdx ? `${parentIdx}.` : ''}${idx + 1}`;
    // add parent to new array
    newArray.push({...child, level});
    // recursively flatten children
    flatten(children, level);
  })
}

flatten(arr)

console.log(newArray)
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this is required, but with such a solution it will not be possible to solve the problem for 3000 or more nested elements